# Storing variable value in function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

So, in a React class component, I can add a property super easily:

```
export default class Thing extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.hasRunQuery = false
    }

    handleClick = () => {
        this.hasRunQuery = true
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
                Click 
            </button>
        )
    }
```

When it unmounts/remounts, this variable is of course re-set (as it's a new instance of the class). Function components don't appear to have this luxury:

```
let hasRunQuery = false

export default () => {
    handleSubmit = () => {
        hasRunQuery = true
    }

    return (
        <button onClick={handleSubmit}>
            Click
        </button>
    )
}
```

If the above component unmounts and re-mounts, `hasRunQuery` will still be true. If there are 10 instances of this component, they'll somehow all share the same variable.

Short of storing any and all properties in `useState`, is there any means of setting variables in function components that don't keep their value once unmounted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In functional components this is achieved with `useRef`

```
export default () => {
    const hasRunQuery = useRef(false)

    const handleSubmit = () => {
        hasRunQuery.current = true
    }

    return (
        <button onClick={handleSubmit}>
            Click
        </button>
    )
}
```

For more information, [see the api documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref), plus [this section of the faq](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables)

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you so much, Nicholas.